# Python MySQL Connection Pooling with Connection Idle Timeout option

Tags: python, mysql, connection, timeout, connection-pooling

I was looking at different python modules available for MySQL connection pooling but it seems none of them support connection idle timeout. This would be the timeout to automatically remove idle connections from the pool.

I have looked into the following modules:

- pymysql
- mysql-connector-python
- pymysql-pool
- DBUtils

Does anyone know any module that would support connection idle timeout or has any workaround for this?

Comment: Hi @kaptan, did you found a solution in the mean time?

Comment: @DarkMath No, I couldn't find a workaround. Please let me know if you find anything.

Comment: Not really. But what is your actual need behind your question? How do you define an "idle connection"? Do you mean a server-side closed connection?
At least `DBUtils` allow you to ping the connections automatically which will perform a reconnect if the connection was already closed by the DBMS.

Comment: @DarkMath Please take a look at `idleTimeout` definition in [Hikari JDBC connection pool](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#:~:text=30000%20(30%20seconds)-,idleTimeout,-This%20property%20controls): `This property controls the maximum amount of time that a connection is allowed to sit idle in the pool.`

Comment: Okay, I understand. But why are idle connections important to you? I always ping the connections before I receive them and I never had any problems.

Comment: Because I'm using a serverless sql cloud service which would keep charging me if I keep an open connection to the db. So I want the connections to timeout automatically if they are idle.